# How to create a choropleth map of Europe with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, geospatial, colormap

I would like to create a choropleth map of Europe using ggplot.

For this purpose i retrieved data from Eurostat:

- EU: a polygonshapefile containing locations of the NUTS 3 regions
- NM_info: a csv file containing specific data for each of the NUTS 3 regions

The code underneath indeed generated a plot of Europe.

```
  ggplot(EU_join) +
  theme_minimal()+  # no backgroundcolor
  geom_polygon( aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
                color = "white",  
                fill = "#9C9797")
```

As a next step, I expanded above code to color the regions according to their value of EU_join$Value. I tried to run the code underneath.

```
EU_join = merge(EU, NM_info, by.x = "NUTS_ID", by.y = "GEO")

ggplot(EU_join)+
  theme_minimal()+
  geom_polygon( aes(x = long, y = lat, group = EU_join$NUTS_ID, fill= EU_join$Value),
                color = "grey", alpha = 1/5)
```

The length of the group and fill arguments are both 1480. However, I keep getting the error

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (476378): x, y, group, fill

Furthermore, I would like to use a blue palette for negative values of EU_join$Value and a red palette for positive ones. How should I adjust the color of above code to achieve that?

Comment: You can take out the ```EU_join``` in ```geom_polygon()``` to just have: ```geom_polygon( aes(x = long, y = lat, group =NUTS_ID, fill= Value), color = "grey", alpha = 1/5)```. If you want red/blue for positive/negative, you'll either need to create an indicator variable (so that it's categorical) or use ```scale_colour_gradient2```.

Comment: For the indicator variable, something like ```EU_join$category = ifelse(EU_join$Value >= 0, "positive", "negative")```